# Middleware apparently not working for post request (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: laravel, http, nginx

I have middleware that redirects the user if it it not logged in. The user is not prevented from filling in the form, only when he submits the data my middleware comes in to check if he is authenticated. It seems like it is not passing throught the middleware at all when the submit button is clicked.

My route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'allow.access'], function(){

Route::post('houses', [                     //I wonder if I defined this
'as' => 'houses.store',                      //route correctly because
'uses' => 'HousesController@store'      //it seems Laravel is ignoring it
]);

Route::get('houses/{id}/edit', [
'as' => 'houses.edit',
'uses' => 'HousesController@edit'
]);



});
```

My middleware works if I use this route inside the group:

```
Route::get('houses/create/{zip}', [
'as' => 'houses.create',
'uses' => 'HousesController@create'
]);
```

my middleware

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{


    if(!$request->session()->has('loginInfo'))
    {
       return  redirect()->route('register.login');
    }

      return $next($request);
}
```